# Interpreting Slater-Koster files for DFTB

Tags: computational-physics, software, tight-binding

I have a question about interpreting [.SKF files](http://www.dftb.org/parameters/download/), I am using these parameters to model defective graphene,

when I use parameter set given here: [dftbBaby/C-C](http://www.dftbaby.chemie.uni-wuerzburg.de/DFTBaby/mdwiki.html#!WIKI/parametrization.md) (I think this is from Hotbit) or the parameter set given by the following paper:

Porezag, D., Frauenheim, T., Köhler, T., Seifert, G., & Kaschner, R. (1995). Construction of tight-binding-like potentials on the basis of density-functional theory: Application to carbon. Physical Review B, 51(19), 12947.

(please note that both give $H_{pp\pi}$ ~−3eV at an interatomic distance of ~ 1.4 Angstrom) then after performing slater-koster transformations and embedding the $H0$ and $S$ values into the secular equation, I get the correct band structure.

however, for other parameterizations, for example say [dftb/mio](http://www.dftb.org/parameters/download/mio/mio-1-1-cc/), the value I get for $H_{pp\pi}$ from interpolation of hopping integrals is much smaller ~-2eV and gives wrong band structure:
[image: extracted integrals from dftb.org/mio-1-1/C-C.SKF]

Fig. Extracted integrals from dftb.org/mio-1-1/C-C.SKF

[image: Wrong_Band_Structure_of_graphene]
Fig. **WRONG** band structure, please note that the band width of the calculated conduction band (5th band) should be ~10eV not ~5eV.

here for sure it is me who is doing sth wrong because using the same parameter set DFTB+ gives the correct band structure,

I am not sure whether I am not interpreting the SKF files properly (in a naive attempt the band structure can be corrected by increasing the value of the minimum interatomic distance $r_0$ given in the SKF file which is equal to shifting the curves downwards or alternatively by increasing $|H_{pp\pi}|$) or is there any other step that I need to perform before embedding the H and S values into the secular equation?

Answer (score 0):

I figured that I was using the wrong format, the detailed format of .SKF files is given [here](http://www.dftb.org/fileadmin/DFTB/public/misc/slakoformat.pdf)

The correct extracted parameterization profile is given below:

[image]